# Calling DLL function with char* param from C#?

Tags: c#

I have a C++ dll that I need to call from C#.  One of the functions in the dll requires a char* for an input parameter, and another function uses a char* as an output parameter.

What is the proper way to call these from C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using strings will work fine for input parameters, though you can control details about the string with the MarshalAs attribute.  E.g.

```
[DllImport("somedll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern void Func([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string wideString);
```

As for returning char* parameters, that's a little more complex since object ownership is involved.  If you can change the C++ DLL you can use CoTaskMemAllocate, with something like:

```
void OutputString(char*& output)
{
    char* toCopy = "hello...";
    size_t bufferSize = strlen(toCopy);
    LPVOID mem = CoTaskMemAlloc(bufferSize);
    memcpy(mem, toCopy, bufferSize);
    output = static_cast<char*>(mem);
}
```

The C# side then just uses an 'out string' parameter, and the garbage collector can pick up the ownership of the string.

Another way of doing it would be to use a StringBuilder, but then you need to know how big the string will be before you actually call the function.

Answer (score 3):

string should work if the parameter is read-only, if the method modifies the string you should use StringBuilder instead.

Example from reference below:

```
 [DllImport ("libc.so")]
 private static extern void strncpy (StringBuilder dest, 
      string src, uint n);

 private static void UseStrncpy ()
 {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder (256);
    strncpy (sb, "this is the source string", sb.Capacity);
    Console.WriteLine (sb.ToString());
 }
```

If you don't know how p/invoke marshaling works you could read http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries

If you are only conserning with strings, read only the section: http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries#Strings

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this works, but have you tried with

```
StringObject.ToCharArray();
```

Not sure about initialising the String from char * tho. Mybe just assign to a string object, its worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried StringBuilder? I found this in a Google search:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetUserName(StringBuilder lpBuffer, ref int nSize);
```

If you post the call you're making we can help you assemble it.

Answer (score 0):

If the DLL function is expecting an allocated buffer of `char*` (not a wide/multibyte buffer) then the following will work:

```
[DllImport("somedll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void TheFunc(byte[] someBuffer, int someSize);
```

Here a buffer allocated in c# is passed to `TheFunc` which fills it with a string of characters (of type char).  Bytes aren't "interpreted" by C# they are treated like 8 bit integers, so are perfect for holding 8 bit characters.

An example code snipped would therefore be:

```
byte[] mybuffer;
int bufSize;

bufSize = 2048;
mybuffer = new byte[bufSize];

TheFunc(mybuffer, bufSize);

string value;
for(value = "", int ix  = 0; (mybuffer[ix] != 0) && (ix < bufSize); ix++)
  value += (char) mybuffer[ix];

DoSomethingWithTheReturnedString(value);
```